# Multiplying all values in IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have the following code and I am trying to work out how to multiply all values in my `IEnumerable<int>`.

I thought there might by a Multiply method like there is with Sum. I guess I could do a foreach over each item but these days this seems tedious.

Any suggestions?

```
//1:2:6
string[] pkgratio = comboBox1.SelectedRow.Cells["PkgRatio"].Value.ToString().Split(':');
var ints = pkgratio.Select(x => int.Parse(x));         

int modvalue = ints....
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Aggregate function

```
int modValue = ints.Aggregate(1, (x,y) => x * y);
```

The Aggregate function takes in an initial accumulator value and then applies an operation to every value in the enumeration creating a new accumulator value.  Here we start with 1 and then multiply ever value by the current value of the accumulator.

Note: In the case of an empty `ints` value this will return 1.  This may or may not be correct for your situation.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried ints.Aggregate(1, (x,y) => x + y); and for 1,2,6 it add up to 10. I guess that is because it adds 1 to start with. Multiplying however will be ok??

Comment: @Jon: Yes. You can also omit the seed altogether and do `ints.Aggregate((x,y) => x * y)` but that will throw an exception if you feed it an empty sequence.

Comment: I just tried and it throws an exception anyway even if the seed is there on a empty sequence

Comment: Just an FYI, in case you are working with floating point numbers instead of ints, you would want to change the "1" to "1.0" or cast it to your actual type, otherwise you will get a compiler error.  Seems obvious in hindsight, but I spent a few minutes scratching my head on it and thought I would share this to hopefully spare others having to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, just what I've been looking for!